# MapReduce job fails with ExitCodeException exitCode=255

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, shared-libraries, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a MapReduce job that requires a shared library (a .so file). If I use the shared library from an standalone Java program I don't have problems at all (this program used java.library.path to find the library), but if I try to use the same native methods from the MapReduce program then I obtain the exception I pasted below (for the MapReduce program I am using the Distributed cache).

I know the native library is actually being loaded and the native code (C++) is called from MapReduce since the native function prints something to the standard output but after the native function returns I see a **"Signal caught, exiting"** message and then the application logs only provide the information below (I think the 255 is a -1 in this case) but that's it, I don't know where else to look for information to debug this issue or to figure out out why there is an uncaught signal. Any pointers about where to look for debugging/log info are appreciated.

> Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=255:
>   ExitCodeException exitCode=255:   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved my own problem, but I am not sure about how to explain this. In C++ I have a method that returns to Java a pointer as a jlong (I was casting the pointer to jlong) and everything worked OK when the library was called from a standalone application, but the same code failed when called from Yarn.

I wrote a custom signal handler and that helped me know that it was a segment fault error, so I was doing something wrong with the pointers or the memory. When trying to call the same library from MapReduce (Yarn) is when I was having the previous exception. I changed the cast for the pointer to long instead of jlong and that is what I returned to Java. Later, when the handle to the native object was invoked the problem was not happening again. I am not sure why this helped, but something is going on with how Yarn manipulates the environment.

Best regards.

Comment: So from a Hadoop admin perspective... one reason this may be happening is if some of the YARN nodes don't have the libs needed for jlong, it will fail on just those nodes causing the entire job to fail. Locally this would run fine as long as this lib is present on that machine it's executing from.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the MR program encounter the problem when run the shell program. Please check the correctness of your C++ program.